# R plot does not display scatter plot

Tags: r

The data is 'Heights of Presidents of the United States and presidential candidates', you can find it [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heights_of_presidents_and_presidential_candidates_of_the_United_States). I loaded the data into R by using command:

```
height = read.csv('heights.csv')
```

The variables are the columns title. There are 2 heights data, so R automatically change it to 'height' and 'height.1'.

Now, I want to display a scatter plot comparing 'height' and 'height.1'. When I type the command:

```
plot(height$Height, height$Height.1)
```

I got:

[image]

What's wrong here?

Comment: If you would like to see screenshots, insert links to them, anyone with enough reputation will edit the question.

Comment: Not nearly enough information to help you out. You've given the wiki page with the heights, but not explained how you read it in to R (factors? numerical? ... try `head(height)`). What's Height.1? Also, your question title says that R does *not* display a scatter plot, but your question says that qplot gives you a "nice scatter plot". So..what's wrong? What command are you using in qplot? Do you want a scatter plot? Do you not want a scatter plot? what is your question?

Comment: ups sorry. I'll edit it.

Comment: Show us your data. You have factors/characters somewhere. Have you tried `plot(height$Height ~ height$Height.1)`?

Comment: The data is exactly what is on wikipedia, see the link above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entries such as `"185 cm"` are not interpeted as numeric values.

Try stripping the `cm` away from the columns and coercing them to be numeric.

```
h.numeric <- height
h.numeric$Height <- as.numeric(as.character(gsub(" cm", "", h.numeric$Height)))
h.numeric$Height.1 <- as.numeric(as.character(gsub(" cm", "", h.numeric$Height.1)))

plot(Height, Height.1, data=h.numeric, xlab = "Height (cm)", ylab = "Height.1 (cm)")
```

Comment: But why can I plot it with qplot (from ggplot2) and not with plot?

Comment: Because they're different functions.

Comment: 'cm' is really the cause of the problem. Thanks Hugh!